# I am using React, Formik and Axios however Axios seems to be making two api calls one after the other

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, formik

I am using React, Formik and Axios however when I make the axios calls, Axios seems to be making two api calls one after the other in succession.

What a I doing wrong? How can I avoid this? Any help much appreciated.

Added code sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-einstein-e9609?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
const handleFormSubmit = (values, {setSubmitting}) => {
    const {artifact, match_strategy, merge_strategy} = values;
    setIsDisabled(true);
    setUploadArtifactError(<span className="text-success"><b>Processing...</b></span>)

    getImageAsBytes(values.artifact)
        .then(data => {
            setSubmitting(false)
            postArtifact(data, artifact, match_strategy, merge_strategy);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('Convert as bytes error ', error);
            setIsDisabled(false);
        });

}
```

- 

```
const postArtifact = (payload, file, match_strategy, merge_strategy) => {
    setUploadArtifactError(<span className="text-success"><b>Uploading ...</b></span>)
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}artifact/load?name=${file.name}`, payload)
        .then(res => {
            const {_id, blob_url } = res.data.data;
            const payload = {
                "ref": `${file.name}_${new Date().getMilliseconds()}`,
                "config": {
                    "match_strategy": match_strategy,
                    "merge_strategy": merge_strategy,
                    "artifact_ids" : [_id]
                }
            }
            // console.log('artifact upload res ', _id, blob_url)
            if(res.status === 200) {
                postLoadSites(payload);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('artifact upload error ', error)
            setUploadArtifactError(<span className="text-warning"><b>Unable to upload at this time, (try different Match or Merge Strategy) or please try again later</b></span>);
            setIsDisabled(false);
        })
}
```

- 

```
const postLoadSites = (payload) => {
    axios.post(`${baseUrl}load/sites`, payload)
        .then(res => {
            if(res.status === 200) {
                setUploadSitesError(<span className="text-success"><b>Uploaded Sites Successfully!</b></span>);
                setUploadArtifactError('');
                setIsDisabled(false);
                handleMultiUploadCallback();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("multi site upload error ", error);
            setUploadSitesError(<span className="text-warning"><b>Unable to upload at     this time, (try different Match or Merge Strategy) or please try again later</b></span>);
            setIsDisabled(false)
        })
}
```

This is how the network looks
[image]

Comment: How are you calling `handleFormSubmit` ? It would be better to see the whole component. Can you post a code sandbox?

Comment: I will create a CodeSandbox but this is where handleFormSubmit is being called  <Formik
                    initialValues={INITIAL_VALUES}
                    onSubmit={(values, {setSubmitting}) => handleFormSubmit(values, {setSubmitting})}
                    validator={() => ({})}
                >

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/embed/clever-einstein-e9609?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark